# Where can i download the U2U CAML query Builder for Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, caml

I have try to download form below links. But the site is not opening.

http://www.u2u.be/res/Tools/files/CamlBuilderSetupv4.0.0.0.zip .

http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx

http://www.u2u.be/Software (In Zip file it has only wsp. file. I did not have permission to deploy the Wsp file.

Answer (score 40):

## CAML Designer

The one that works is this URL: http://camldesigner.blob.core.windows.net/offlinepackage/CamlDesigner2013.zip

The link comes from Karine Bosch's [Blog](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/caml-designer/). CAML Designer is the successor of CAML Builder, and from experience I can tell you this tool is much better and accurate. I've tried the both.

***Edit:** Looks like the CAML Designer now is a subscription application, but it is present on GitHub. https://github.com/chrisdee/Tools/tree/master/SharePoint/CamlDesigner*

## CAML Builder

But if you want the previous tool, the page to turn to is http://www.u2u.be/Software where you have the download at http://www.u2u.be/Downloads/U2U.SharePoint.CQB2010.zip which contains the wsp.

The CamlBuilderSetup.msi-file is located here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1H-kV-5gwStUlF1OEdjWWJZNXc/edit?pli=1

Comment: Do you have the older version of U2U CAML query designer. I am trying to use this query designer for SharePoint2003 which this version does not allows me to do.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

U2U CAML Query Builder is now available again and updated for SharePoint 2013:

http://www.u2u.be/Software

You can also check out these alternatives:

[Stramit Caml Viewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/)

[SharePoint CAML Query Helper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/)

[Caml Designer for SP 2010 and SP 2013](http://www.biwug.be/resources)

[CAML Generator](http://www.CAMLGenerator.com/)

(taken from my post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420835/u2u-caml-query-builder-no-longer-available/16526846#16526846))

Answer (score 2):

There is a GUI editor on Visual Studio Gallery

[CAML Query Builder](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b39025f-f48f-440c-b056-f7d227f7c798)

Comment: that link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created CAML Query designer based on my own requirements and I am giving that as an utility for free. Hope this will help SharePoint developers in better way.

http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2015/02/download-caml-query-designer.html

Comment: This tool is not working. Nothing is happening clicking on Connect.

Comment: Oh... Can you please tell me your environment of connecting the site? or do you have .net 4.5 Framework installed?

Comment: I am working with SP2013 and yes i do have 4.5

Comment: Can you send me the log file to battula at outlook.com please?

Comment: I uninstalled it :(