# Building CAML query with AND and Order by Clause

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, caml

Hi I am trying to build a query using caml query builder - Below is the query (The query = get the values only whose **address = 1234st AND LastName = Doe**) - I believe the placement of AND operator is giving me error,  tried various permutation by changing the position of AND operators but no luck - any suggestions?

```
<OrderBy>
 <FieldRef Name = "ID" Ascending = "TRUE"/>
</OrderBy>
<Where>
 <And>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name = "HomeType"><Value Type="Choice">Condo</FieldRef>
  </Eq>
 <And>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name = "LastName"><Value Type="Text">Doe</FieldRef>
  </Eq>
 </And>
 </And>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="TRUE"/>
</OrderBy>
<Where>
 <And>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name="HomeType"/><Value Type="Choice">Condo</Value>
  </Eq>
  <Eq>
   <FieldRef Name="LastName"/><Value Type="Text">Doe</Value>
  </Eq>
 </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: Also no spaces around the equal sign. `Name = "` becomes `Name="`.

Comment: cleaned those up

Comment: Spaces around the equal sign i.e. Name = " do not create any issue.

Comment: `<FieldRef>` don't want a body!!! The answer of @ilMattion is right.

Comment: @Emaborsa what are you referring to?

Comment: You wrote `<FieldRef Name="HomeType"><Value Type="Choice">Condo</Value></FieldRef>`. This is wrong, The right format is `<FieldRef Name = "HomeType" /><Value Type="Choice">Condo</Value>`

Comment: You're right, I double checked it again BIWUG. I've edited the answer to reflect that. tyvm.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this code:

```
<Eq>
 <FieldRef Name = "HomeType"><Value Type="Choice">Condo</FieldRef>
</Eq>
```

must be like that:

```
<Eq>
   <FieldRef Name = "HomeType" /><Value Type="Choice">Condo</Value>
</Eq>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CAML query buider from U2U, it's really helpful.
It will build the queries for you

Comment: U2U CAML query builder link to download is dead now. I use CAML designer (freeware) from http://www.camldesigner.com/. Works for both 2010 and 2013 and pretty intuitive way to build queries.

Comment: CAML query builder links question is answered: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/72165/62

Answer (score 1):

You had an extra `<And>` and `</And>`.  Just remember that you only need a set of those around every 2 fields (or groups) you are comparing.  Ex.

```
<Where>
 <And>
     <And>
       <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="HomeType"><Value Type="Choice">Condo</FieldRef>
       </Eq>
       <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="LastName"><Value Type="Text">Doe</FieldRef>
       </Eq>
     </And>
     <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"><Value Type="Integer">1</FieldRef>
     </Eq>
   </And>
</Where>
```

And this is also valid.  Notice the grouping of two items per 'And', then an 'And' between the two groups:

```
<Where>
 <And>
     <And>
       <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="HomeType"><Value Type="Choice">Condo</FieldRef>
       </Eq>
       <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name="LastName"><Value Type="Text">Doe</FieldRef>
       </Eq>
     </And>
     <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Rooms"><Value Type="Integer">2</FieldRef>
      </Eq>         
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Location"><Value Type="Text">Brooklyn</FieldRef>
      </Eq>
     </And>
   </And>
</Where>
```