# CAML query with Five Condtion throws an Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPException

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

```
         string query = <Where> 
                           <And>    
                              <And>       
                                 <And>          
                                      <Eq></Eq>
                                      <Eq></Eq>
                                 </And>
                                   <Geq></Geq>
                                   <Leq></Leq>
                              </And>       
                                <Eq></Eq>
                           </And>
                        </Where>
```

In SharePoint foundation development, i have used this CAML query to query a SharePoint list. This query contains five conditions. After above query gets executed, it throws an Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPException exception. I tried but couldn't figure it out. Is there any mistake in above CAML query. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 child elements under the second And element: And, Geq and Leq. 
It is not supported. Wrap Geq and Leq elements with an additional And parent element and it will work.

Or, as suggested in other answers, use CAML query builder to generate your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your query. The below query I generated with U2U tool

```
<Where>
      <And>
         <And>
            <And>
               <Eq>

               </Eq>
               <Eq>

               </Eq>
            </And>
            <Eq>

            </Eq>
         </And>
         <Eq>

         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>
```

It should follow this format.

Download link for U2U and reference

http://www.u2u.be/Software

[Where can i download the U2U CAML query Builder for Sharepoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72164/where-can-i-download-the-u2u-caml-query-builder-for-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: My query contains Five conditions. Furthermore your query contains four conditions, as i know it can be written with two ANDs. I think, three ANDs are not needed.

Comment: Why don't you use U2U Caml Query builder tool and verify the query.

Comment: can u just send me a link to download U2U Caml Query builder tool.

Comment: I added it to the answer above...pls have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a hurry, to avoid errors in CAML query, try to build the query using [CAML Query Builder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458008/CAML-Query-Builder).

Hope this helps you.